# Conjugacy classes of subgroups of $D_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

This problem is from Michael Artin Algebra first edition.

> 6.3.3) List all subgroups of the dihedral group $D_{4}$ and divide them into conjugacy classes.

I am a bit unsure what I am being asked here since, so far, I have been thinking of conjugacy classes as sets of elements of a group and not sets of subgroups of a group.

The subgroups of $D_{4}$ I have found, where $x$ is a rotation of order 4 and $y$ is a reflection, are:

$D_{4}, \{e\}, \{e, x, x^{2}, x^{3}\}, \{e, x^{2}\}, \{e, y\}, \{e, yx\}, \{e, yx^{2}\}, \{e, x^{2}, y, yx^{2}\}, \{e, yx^{3}\}, \{e, x^{2}, yx, yx^{3}\}$

Comment: A few hints. clearly $D_{4}$ and $\{ e \}$ are normal subgroups, and so their conjugacy classes are singletons. The subgroups of order 4, and thus index $2$, are also normal. You are left with the subgroups of order $2$, of which you have to determine the conjugates. You know that $y^{-1} x y = x^{-1}$, so $y^{-1} x^{2} y = x^{-2} = x^{2}$. (I know that $y^{-1} = y$, but I am writing the inverse for clarity.) Then compute $x^{-1} y x = \dots$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for the hints. I did that before I asked the question but I wasn't completely sure because it wasn't consistent with what I found online. The conjugacy classes I found are singletons for everything but $\{\{e, y\}, \{e, yx^{2}\}\}$ and $\{\{e, yx\}, \{e, yx^{3}\}\}$. So in other words we were looking for the conjugacy classes under action of $D_{4}$ on its subgroups. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the help of Andreas Caranti in the comments, we can say that Artin is interested in the conjugacy classes under the action of $D_{4}$ on its subgroups. By testing the conjugacy action of the elements of $D_{4}$ on each of the following subgroups: $D_{4}, \{e\}, \{e, x, x^{2}, x^{3}\}, \{e, x^{2}\}, \{e, y\}, \{e, yx\}, \{e, yx^{2}\}, \{e, x^{2}, y, yx^{2}\}, \{e, yx^{3}\}, \{e, x^{2}, yx, yx^{3}\}$, we find that $\{\{e, y\},\{e, yx^{2}\}\}$ and $\{\{e, yx\},\{e, yx^{3}\}\}$ are the only conjugacy classes that are not singletons.

For a simple example of how one would check for the conjugacy classes, take $x\in D_{4}$ and the subgroup $\{e, yx^{2}\}$. We have $xyx^{2}x^{-1}=xyx^{2}x^{3}=xyx^{4}x=xyx=yx^{3}x=y$, so that $\{e, yx^{2}\}$ is conjugate to $\{e, y\}$. We can check for the rest of conjugacy classes in a similar way.